# "Shared" section of the sidebar very long to appear in OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder, sidebar

After being very satisfied with my MacBook Pro running OS X 10.6.8, I advised a non-technical-skilled relative to buy one, which she did. The MacBook Pro came with OS X 10.8.2 but there is a problem. The "Shared" section of the sidebar is very long to appear, sometime more than 5 minutes.

Considering this "Shared" section appears as soon as I am logged on my MacBook, I guess the recently bought MacBook Pro (2.5 GHz Intel Core i5) could do, at least, as good as mine (2.4 GHz Intel Core i5) which was bought 2 years earlier.

Does anyone know if there is a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "very long to appear"? Do you not see the word "Shared" at first? Does it take a long time for shared computers to populate? Is this person on the same network as you?

Comment: @bispymusic I mean minutes: 5, 10, ... I did not measured it precisely. On my MacBook, it is neither minutes, nor secondes because it appears as soon as I see the sidebar in a freshly opened finder window in my freshly turned on MacBook.

Comment: @bispymusic So no, **at first**, I don't see neither the "Shared" section nor the computers on the network. It takes minutes for the computers to populate.
The person seems to be in the same network because, after few minutes, the computers on the networks finally appear. However, in **her** MacBook in System Preferences > Network > Advanced > WINS tab > Workgroup field, I see "WORKGROUP" selected and it always come back even after I delete it. While, on my MacBook, nothing is selected in this field.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the machine speed, most likely with the network settings and how many machines are on the network. Try to delete the workgroup entry and then lock the System Preferences (padlock on the bottom left side). Also, when you say "The person seems to be in the same network... " do you refer to the same network as you, i.e. are both your and her machines on the same network? Finally, do you use Sharing? If not, why not disable it.

Comment: @lupincho deleting the workgroup entry and then locking the padlock does not help. Yes, I referred to the same network as me. If by Sharing you mean file sharing, then yes, the person uses it. I performed a test by disabling it just to verify and... that does not change anything!